# библиотека aFileChooser. Не могу открыть указанную директорию для выбора файла

Tags: java, android

вот библиотека. внизу есть и документация к ней `https://bintray.com/rameeshakulapc/maven/aFileChooser#`

Как я понял библиотека дает готовое окно для загрузки файлов на основе  Activity и если вдруг в телефоне нет предустановленных файловых менеджеров, открывается именно этот. Но должен ведь быть метод чтобы открыть сразу нужную мне директорию.

Я сохраняю файл таким образом (а какое будет расширение у моего файла?)

`OutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(FILE_DataRate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(answer);
            os.close();`

и хочу получить окно где я смогу выбрать этот файл для загрузки.

Использую библиотеку так:

```
public void onClickLoad(View view){

  FileUtils.getPath(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://myapp.exchangerates/"));

        Intent getContentIntent = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();

        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(getContentIntent, "Select a file");

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

        }
```

И всё равно хоть я и добавил Path, открывается активити где я не нахожу в какой либо директории.

Comment: "а какое будет расширение у моего файла?" - что у Вас в  `FILE_DataRate`, то и будет именем файла (расширение - это часть имени, если в имени нет точки - файл будет без расширения)

Comment: `Context.openFileOutput()` пишет в директорию, которую можно получить методом `context.getFilesDir()`. Но в этой библиотеке не предусмотрено старта с указанной директории, да и давненько она не обновлялась. Либо Вам придётся дописывать в неё функционал, склонировав к себе в проект с [GitHab' а](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser), либо поискать более подходящую.

Comment: спасибо, это я и хотел услышать , ибо перелопатил всю библиотеку, но так и не смог найти ничего, чтобы запустить сразу нужную директорию. Можете добавить как ответ, я приму

Comment: И может знаете какую нибудь библиотеку удобную, чтобы сразу открыть указанную директорию, желательно с фильтром по расширениям